# find the 4 biggest elements of an array by using a simple brute force algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, brute-force

I have an array (`myDb`) that contains songs and their duration. I need to find the 4 songs with the longest duration by using a brute force algorithm, but I'm kind of too stupid to make it work. First I made a loop to find my longest song like this (works):

```
CTitle tmp=*myDb.getTitle(0);
for (int i=0; i<=myDb.getNumberofTitles;i++)
{
    if (tmp.getDuration()<myDb.getTitle(i+1)->getDuration())
    {
        tmp=*myDb.getTitle(i+1)
    }
}
```

So this works and I have my longest track saved as my temporary object.
Now I have to search `myDb` for a title that has this duration and add it into my "playlist" (array of `CTitles`). Than I have to decrease the duration (integer, represents duration of a track in seconds) by one and search my array for a track that has this duration and add it to my playlist, if there is no one than again decrease duration by one and search again.

It seems to me that i have to do 2 for loops one to go through my array and the other one to decrease my duration, I tried it on every ways I could think of, but it never worked like it had to work. Thats my best attempt for now, but it doesn't stop when my array reached 4 elemtens:

```
    for(int k=tmp.getDuration();k>=0; k--)
    {
        for (int m=0; m<myDb.getNumberOfTitles();m++)
        {
            if (myDb.getTitle(m)->getDuration()==k)
            {
                playlist2.add(myDb.getTitle(m));
            }     
        }
    }

playlist2.print();
```

Comment: Decrementing won't work if you have two songs with the same duration. And it will take a very long time if there is one song that's an hour long (say, Beethoven's 9th Symphony) and the rest are short. Consider using `std::partition` instead.

Comment: It's a task for my school, so we have to do it by decrementing, the longest song in the Database is 500s long. They want us to learn how a Brute-Force like algorithm works. Also there aren't any songs with the same duration.

Comment: Search for a song of lenght 500s, search for a song of lenght 499s, ect... Stop when 4 songs have been found?

Comment: Yes, exactly like this.

Comment: I suppose there is sme tiny value in learning the wrong way, but not much.

Answer (score -1):

```
size_t i;
size_t place;
size_t size = 4;
CTitle tmps[size];
for (i = 0; i < size && i <= myDb.getNumberofTitles; i++) {
    tmps[i] = *myDb.getTitle(i);
}
std::sort(tmps, tmps + size, [](const CTitle &a, const CTitle &b) {
    return a.getDuration() > b.getDuration();
});
for (i = size; i <= myDb.getNumberofTitles; i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if (tmps[j].getDuration() < myDb.getTitle(i + 1)->getDuration()) {
            place = j;
            for (j = size - 1; j > place; j--) {
                tmps[j] = tmps[j - 1];
            }
            tmps[place] = *myDb.getTitle(i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tested it, it seems to work, but you are using a vector and the size() function. My "Playlist" is an array of CTitles, so I am not allowed to use the size() function. The whole sort and add part of this tasks works fine for me, i just don't know how to stop my loops when I reached 4 elements in my Playlist, because it's a dynamic array and I couldn't find any c++ feature to read out the size of a dynamic array and I'm not allowed to program any other than the given functions of my tutor

Comment: @mqdrt64 I edited the answer to array instead of vector. try this one.

Comment: `tmps` contains all titles sorted by duration, right? So why not simply take the first four elements?

Comment: `size_t size = 4; CTitle tmps[size];` -- This is not legal C++, and will not compile if the compiler the tutor uses adheres to standard C++ rules.  This should be `const size_t size = 4;`.

Comment: @idmean no.. myDb contains all the titles with the durations, and I don't know if we can sort this element.

Comment: @KorelK [VLA](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) is a compiler extension and not part of the c++ standard.